# sed command in Python using json.dumps of a quoted string does not keep the single quote

Tags: python, json, sed, escaping, single-quotes

Sorry if the title is little bit convoluted... An example will show better what I mean:

I have a text file named foo that contains the string 'bar'.

In Python, I have a dictionary :

```
d = {"key": "item['id']"}
```

I want to replace the string bar in my file with a json dump of my dictionary. Commands:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("sed 's#bar#%s#g' foo > foo2" % json.dumps(d),shell=True)
```

When I cat the file foo2, result is:

```
> cat foo2
{"key": "item[id]"}
```

Problem is: the single quotes are lost around id. How can I avoid that?

Comment: Why even try to use sed? Do it all in python.

Comment: well...maybe because I thought it was shorter with a single sed command. Do you think about re.sub?

Comment: Can you please share input record from `foo`

Comment: @DigvijayS foo = "bar"

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Shawn I did it all in Python with "python sed" function that is based on re.sub:

```
def psed(foo,bar,source,dest):
    """
    implements a python sed, substituting (with multi-line mode) foo for bar 
    in file source, writing the result in file dest
    """
    with open(source,'r') as f:
        content = f.read()
    f.close()
    content_new = re.sub(foo,bar,content,flags=re.M)

    with open(dest,'w') as f:
        f.write(content_new)
    f.close()
```